# wix - error CNDL0004: The file element contains an unexpected attribute "src" when running from the command line

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.8

When I run the below command from the command line for the WIx installer after migrated from version 2.0 to 4.0

```
E:\Code\PCPE\builder>ant -v -f Build.xml -Dlabel =.001 install
```

I am getting the below error:

```
error CNDL0004: The file element contains an unexpected attribute "src"
```

I am seeing the error in EMR_COMMON.wxs file in line no 4.

1. Fragment>
2. DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
3. Component Id="component_COMMON" Guid="" DiskId="1">
4. File Id="file0_COMMON" Name="apcrun.exe" src="E:\Code\apcrun.exe"/>

I am thinking that "src" attribute is deprecated and it should be replaced with some other attribute.

But here i can't directly replace the `"src"` attribute in `EMR_COMMON.wxs` file bcz it is generating from `"Build.xml"`.

So what are the attributes i need to change in `"Build.xml"` file to get the appropriate attribute inplace of `"src"` in `"EMR_COMMON.wxs"` file?

Comment: Yes, **`src`** is deprecated in favor of **`Source`** for [**File Elements**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html) (towards bottom). As to **`Build.xml`**, is that an Ant build script? Are you using Visual Studio, Eclipse, or something else?

Comment: You can add an answer from yourself and set it as accepted. So whoever has a similar issue can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I write the below C# code to replace `src` attribute name with `Source` attribute.

For this first i got the `File` node list, get the count of the file nodes and then used

```
XmlNodeList fileNodeList = compElement.GetElementsByTagName("File"); 
XmlElement fileElement = (XmlElement)fileNodeList[i]; 
String srcString = fileElement.GetAttribute("src"); 
fileElement.SetAttribute("Source", srcString); 
fileElement.RemoveAttribute("src");
```